# ES6 spread elements vs nested forEach performance

Tags: performance, ecmascript-6

I have the following function

```
const modules = [{courses:[...]},{courses:[...]},...]
const deleteCourses = [];
modules.forEach((mod) => {
    mod.courses.forEach((course) => {
        deleteCourses.push(course));
    }
    // versus
    deleteCourses = [...deleteCourses, ...mod.courses];
});
```

Assuming modules and courses to have between 30-100 length I was wondering which one of those is more efficient?

On the one hand I was taught to avoid nesting `forEach` loops. In the other hand array literal creates a new `Array` instance each time.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, the spread *element* doesn't create an array. The array literal (`[ ]`) is responsible for creating the array.

Comment: Because for the question the fact that you are using spread elements probably doesn't matter much. You can as well be using `[].concat(deleteCourses, mod.courses)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that **nested forEach** is very much faster, as this [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/es6-spread-operator-vs-nested-foreach-performance) shows:

Setup:

```
const modules = Array(30).fill({courses:Array(30).fill(1)}) //30x30 elements
let deleteCourses = [];
```

Case 1: **nested forEach** - *29,293 ops/sec*

```
modules.forEach((mod) => {
    mod.courses.forEach((course) => {
        deleteCourses.push(course);
    })
})
```

Case 2: **ES6 Spread Operator** - *49.13 ops/sec*

```
modules.forEach((mod) => {
    deleteCourses = [...deleteCourses, ...mod.courses];
})
```

That's about 600x faster for that 30x30 sample

This makes sense when you consider the amount of redundancy in respreading `deleteCourses` on every iteration. In contrast to **nested forEach**, the number of addition operations performed per iteration is about the length of `deleteCourses` for that iteration. That number is also growing on every iteration.

So the difference in performance has little to do with the creation of new `Array` instances, and much to do with the multitude of redundant steps created by this misusage of the spread operator.

To be sure, looking at the two cases individually, we can see that:

- the **ES6 Spread Operator** algorithm is exponential: `O(2^n)`
- the **nested forEach** algorithm is linear: `O(n)`

Comment: thanks for that link!! it'll come in handy mightly for testing my reducer functions :)

Comment: Please [don't call it spread *operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196).

Comment: It's quadratic, not exponential.